# How to add (only one) visible gpu device in correct way?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use python3.6.8, TensorFlow-GPU 2.0.0+nv, CUDA V10.2.89

My GPU
[image]
I want to use only 1 GPU Device, So I used this code to add a visible GPU device to Tensorflow

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "7"
os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True)
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
```

But When I'm running the code, there still see other GPU devices
[image]

And Finally, the error said about cuDNN failed to initialize
[image]

But When I decide to use GPU number 0 everything is fine, no error !!!
(The same code and the same environment just change only the GPU device number from 0 to 7)
[image]

P.S. I use a Docker image from Nvidia (nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow), So I think everything is compatible (?)

Comment: It looks like you imported tensorflow before setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`, is that correct? You may need to do it the other way round.

Comment: @myrtlecat Thank you so so much! I called TF before the setting my mistake :(